# C code compilation fails on iOS Yosemite for iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, c, swift, llvm, osx-yosemite

I am getting a strange compilation error while trying to use C code in my app. The error is the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/os/activity.h:38:9: error: declaration of 'uint64_t' must be imported from module 'MachO.arch' before it is required
typedef uint64_t os_activity_t;
```

Complete compiler output for the issue:

```
compileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/AppDelegate.swift
    cd /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/ViewController.swift -primary-file /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/AppDelegate.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.1 -target-cpu core2 -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -I /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -g -import-objc-header /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xcc -I/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/myapp.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++ -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/experimental -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ext -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/coreapi -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/tools -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/common -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/native_lib -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/services -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/ssh -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/ssl -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/common -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/ssh -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/ssl -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/tools/rsa4php -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/services/audio -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/services/bignum -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/services/ciphers -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/bignum -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/ciphers -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/services/audio/common -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio/common -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio/g711 -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio/g729ab -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio/multicodec -Xcc -I../native_lib/source/native_lib/src/services/audio/spirit -Xcc -I/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-module-doc-path /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name myapp -emit-module-path /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d -o /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gmwstsbfdcwhlzdgtdnbfrycgaic/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o

/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: note: while building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:10: note: while building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48:10: note: while building module 'os' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48:
#include <os/object.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/os/activity.h:38:9: error: declaration of 'uint64_t' must be imported from module 'MachO.arch' before it is required
typedef uint64_t os_activity_t;
        ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/../native_lib/source/native_lib/include/common/stdint.h:101:32: note: previous declaration is here
typedef unsigned long long     uint64_t;
                               ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: note: while building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:10: note: while building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48:10: error: could not build module 'os'
#include <os/object.h>
         ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: note: while building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFPropertyList.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFStream.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:10: error: could not build module 'Dispatch'
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
         ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
         ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:9: note: while building module 'Security' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
#import <Security/Security.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:25:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:25:
#include <Security/SecCertificate.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecCertificate.h:38:10: error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CFData.h>
         ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: note: while building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:10:9: note: while building module 'CFNetwork' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:10:
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10: error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
         ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: note: in file included from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h:5:
#import "myappDataIOS.h"
        ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:11:9: error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: note: in file included from /Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h:5:
#import "myappDataIOS.h"
        ^
/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myappDataIOS.h:13:30: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'myappData'
@interface myappData : NSObject
                             ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/dan/dev/myapp-2-mirror/ios/myapp/myapp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I suspect a collision with mine `uint64_t` type, but how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Remove any `typedef` related to `uint64_t` and `#include <stdint.h>` if you haven't done that, to see what happens.

Comment: according to the documentation, '#import' is not well supported and is full of bugs.  My suggestion: replace all '#import' with '#include' and use proper '#ifdef' wrappers in each of the header files.